ChromeDriver and ChromeDriverService Do Not Work
The test server worked well, but when you try to deploy it to another server, it stops working at chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(); even if you remove the ChromeDriverService and immediately use driver = new ChromeDriver(options); the code stops without executing it.
Both servers are the same except for the version and memory. Changing the size of the thread pool from 10 to 1 doesn't work because I was wondering if it was a memory problem.
It stopped before it was initialized, so the log is not even taken.
Main Server - Rocky Linux release 8.10 (Green Obsidian)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          7.5Gi       5.5Gi       926Mi       178Mi       1.1Gi       1.6Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       1.7Gi       303Mi

Test Server - Rocky Linux release 8.9 (Green Obsidian)
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       6.6Gi       2.4Gi       477Mi       6.4Gi       8.0Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi       843Mi       1.2Gi

I use Selenium Java 4.22.0, Chrome 126, ChromeDriver 126
@Log4j2
public class SeleniumCrawlerDriver implements AutoCloseable {

    private static final ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
    private static final String CHROME_DRIVER = "webdriver.chrome.driver";

    private ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService;
    private WebDriver driver;

    public SeleniumCrawlerDriver() {
        System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER, getChromeDriverPath());
    }

    public boolean create() {

        ChromeOptions options = initChromeOptions();

        log.debug("chrome option init");

        chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
        log.debug("create ChromeDriverService");
////        chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
////                .usingDriverExecutable(new File(getChromeDriverPath()))
////                .usingAnyFreePort()
////                .withLogFile(new File(getChromeDriverLogPath(site.getLogName())))
////                .build();

        driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeDriverService, options);
//        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().scriptTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30));

        return true;
    }

    private ChromeOptions initChromeOptions() {

        String downloadFilepath = getDownloadLocationPath();

        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
        prefs.put("credentials_enable_service", false);
        prefs.put("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
        prefs.put("browser.set_download_behavior", "{behavior : 'allow' , downloadPath: '" + downloadFilepath + "'}");
//        chromeOptions.addArguments("--download.default_directory=/dev/null");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--headless=new");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-server='direct://'");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--proxy-bypass-list=*");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-logging");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--log-level=2");
//        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
        chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        chromeOptions.addArguments("start-maximized");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("enable-javascript");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36");

        return chromeOptions;
    }

}



Is Chrome installed on both servers?  It's not there by default, and installing the driver doesn't install the browser.

Yes, both are installed. It's 126 version

You should try/catch the new ChromeDriver(options); call and include the exception in your post.   If you remove the System.setProperty(CHROME_DRIVER, getChromeDriverPath()); it should automatically download/install driver/browser.

Thank you, but I solved it. It was because the driver crashed inside the Linux server.
